# Not able to write information into linear linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

The processFilefunction scans the information from the file correctly to p, however the addNodeLast function doesn't add the information from p to the linked list employees because it crashes.
Can someone help me fix the crashing, so that it will link each node together?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

void processFile(NODEPTR *employees, FILE *fp);
void outputPayFile(NODEPTR employees);

FILE *fp;

int main(void) {
    NODEPTR employees;

    if (fopen_s(&fp, "payfile2.txt", "r") != 0) {
            printf("Failed to open payfile.txt for reading\n");
            exit(0);
    }
    ...missing code...
}

void processFile(NODEPTR *employees, FILE *fp) {
    int i = 0;
    NODEPTR p;
    while(i < 5) {
            printf("Entered Loop\n");
            p = (NODEPTR) malloc(sizeof(node));

            fscanf(fp, "%s %s %c %d %c %f\n", p->firstName, p->lastName, &(p->gender),
                   &(p->tenure), &(p->rate), &(p->rate), &(p->salary));

            addNodeLast(employees, p);

            i++;
    }
}
```

In list.h:

```
void addNodeLast(NODEPTR *list, NODEPTR t) {
    NODEPTR p;

    if (*list == NULL)
        *list = t;
    else {
        p = *list;
        while (p->next)
            p = p->next;
        p->next = t;
    }
}
```

Definition of NODEPTR:

```
typedef struct node {
    char   firstName[11];
    char   lastName[16];
    char   gender;
    int    tenure;
    char   rate;
    float  salary;
    struct node *next;
} node, *NODEPTR;
```

Comment: The notation `&(p->tenure)` seems odd to anyone experience in C.  While it undoubtedly works, most people normally use `&p->tenure`, which also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialise the `next` pointer.  This is a common mistake.  The call to `malloc` does not zero your memory.  As a result, when you add a node to a non-empty list, you are likely to run straight off the end because the first node's `next` pointer could be non-null.

You need to at least do this:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(node));
if( p != NULL ) p->next = NULL;
```

You could consider using `calloc`, which does zero:

```
p = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
```